# How to convert date string to Solr date format using Python?

Tags: python, date, solr

I am indexing my files using Solr and Python, and I am working on the dates. I have a string dates like `30/01/2013` (ddmmyyy) and `01/30/2013` (mmddyyy). How can I convert these type of dates to Solr date format?

I've been using like this to convert

```
dt = datetime.combine(item[index_field], time())
value_str = dt.isoformat() + 'Z'
```

but got error message `combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str`.

Comment: Are you mixing the two formats? Is there any way for you to determine one or the other is used? What about the date `01/02/2013`?

Comment: Yes, I know when to use `ddmmyyyy` and `mmddyyyy`. My objective is just to convert the date string to Solr format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to parse the strings to dates first (using the [`datetime.datetime.strptime()` class method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), **then** combine with `time()`:

```
format = '%m/%d/%Y' if month_first else '%d/%m/%Y'
datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(item[index_field], format), time())
```

where `month_first` is a boolean that tells you what format to pick.

Officially, `datetime.combine()` takes a `datetime.date` object as the first argument, but in practice it also accepts `datetime.datetime` instances. (You would otherwise have to add a `.date()` call to get the `datetime.date` object from the `datetime.datetime` instance returned by `.strptime()`).

Comment: what does 'item[index_field]' represent ?

Comment: @blah: you'll have to ask the question author that, that's what they are using to pass in a string containing a date to parse.